# Order of timesteps in Keras LSTM training and validation data

Tags: python, keras, lstm

When using Keras recurrent layers, such as an LSTM layer, your input data is supposed to be in the 3-dimensional form of [samples,timesteps,features]. The problem here is that I can't get any reliable information on the order of the timesteps dimension in the input matrices. As a concrete example, would the first element/row, for a given sample, be the most recent known row of features or the most distant row of features?

I would suspect that the order would matter since the model is recurrent, and indeed when flipping the order of the timesteps column you end of getting different training results (when you have appropriately set seeds which would yield reproducibility.)

If someone would force me to guess, I would assume that the first row (for one sample) would be the most distant features in the sequence, but is there a definite answer here?

Answer (score 0):

It's easier to picture 3D arrays in Keras as an array of 2D arrays. The first dimension is the samples.

Your array must be of the shape `[samples, timesteps, features]`. Picture this as an array of length samples, where each element is itself a 2D array of shape `[timesteps, features]`. So, to be clear, each element in this array is a 2D array with `timesteps` number of rows and `features` number of columns.

**The first row (index 0) in each of these 2D arrays is the first timestep, i.e., oldest as you say. The last row in each of these 2D arrays is the last timestep, i.e., most recent.** For each `timestep` row, you have features along the columns.

It helps to unroll the array as done above to picture it easily and with more clarity.

Hope this helped.

Comment: Is there a motivation, a definition, or a logical way of telling why the order of timesteps should be like you say? One of the reason why I was confused in the first place was the usage of the Keras data function tf.keras.preprocessing.timeseries_dataset_from_array, which is used in their own LSTM examples. This functions matches the features against the targets in a strange way, giving you the impression that timesteps should be given in "reverse" order in comparison to what you said.

Comment: I'm not sure if there's a reason for it. However, the Keras docs do mention that the input data must have time on axis 0, which means shape [timesteps, features]. I don't understand what you mean by "reverse", though.

Comment: I'm reffering to Keras's own data pre-processing function, as mentioned above, which matches the outputs against sequences of features in a strange way, e.g. reverse depending on how you seet things. As an example: Let the features be 0,1,2,3,...and y exactly the same. Then that function matches the output 0 to a sequence of [0,1,2,3] if it is of length 4 timesteps, and [0,1,2] if length is equal to 3. This becomes confusing, since this would mean that the first row of timesteps (for a given sample) would be the most recent known array of features, i.e. not what you are saying.